# Inheritance based on environment variable

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a class that has multiple inheritance passed in, but will inherit parent one over the other depending on an environment variable.

```
class Home(
    iOSHome
    if os.environ['platform'] == "ios"
    else AndroidHome
):
```

This works fine, but I'm having troubles getting IntelliJ to recognize any methods from the parent. Is there another way I can get this inheritance working so that PyCharm IntelliJ can recognize it's parent methods?

Comment: Shouldn't they be two different implementations with the same interface, rather than two possible superclasses?

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe. Look at how `pathlib.Path` works.

Comment: iOSHome and AndroidHome should be inheriting from a common Home base / implementing a common Home interface. Otherwise, if AndroidHome has a method like `openGooglePlayStore` which iOS doesn't, then given a Home obejct, how would you (or PyCharm) know whether the `openGooglePlayStore` method exists?